# Merge two zip files using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge two zip files using python.

I had it working, until I realised that it wasn't behaving when it came to the symbolic links that the source zip file contained. Since I was using zipfile.read() on each file when I was adding it to the new zip file, it was reading the symlink and creating a text file, not a symlink.

Does anyone know of a way to get python to preserve the symlink's from the source zip file when I'm writing them to the target zip file?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg34223.html

Comment: When you say merge the two zip files, do you mean zip file A's contents and zip files B's distinct contents into a single zip file? What happens when the same file exists in both? What is the broader goal that requires merging two zip files?

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should be done :

```
      if os.path.islink(filePath):
            attr = zipfile.ZipInfo(filePath)
            attr.create_system = 3 # 3 for unix, 0 for windoze
            attr.external_attr = 2716663808L # to include file as a symlink
            newZip.writestr(attr, os.readlink(filePath))
```